# Bouncing text animation issue in Pygame

Tags: animation, text, pygame, rect

I'm trying to code a program that can take text and animate it to bounce on a loop, like a ball bouncing to the floor. I used a similar piece of code I found a starting point as I'm still fairly new to Pygame (thank you Pete Shinners, whoever you are), but after updating the code and playing with it for a long time I still can't get it to blit to the screen correctly. The text starts above the rendered area and then gradually falls into view, but the top part of the text is cut off.

I've tried moving the blitted region around the window and resizing the rectangles and surface the program is using, but nothing seems to fix it.

```
import os, sys, math, pygame, pygame.font, pygame.image
from pygame.locals import *

def bounce():
    # define constants
    G = 0.98
    FLOOR = 0
    COEFFICIENT = 0.8
    #define variables
    ball = 500
    direction = 'DOWN'
    v = 0
    count = 0
    #create array to store data
    array = [ball]
    while True:
        if count == 4:
            return array
        elif ball > FLOOR and direction == 'DOWN':
            v += G
            if (ball - v) >= FLOOR:
                ball = ball - v
                array.append(round(ball,2))
            else:
                ball = FLOOR
                array.append(round(ball,2))
                direction = 'UP'
                v *= COEFFICIENT
                count += 1
        elif ball >= FLOOR and direction == 'UP':
            v -= G
            if (ball + v) >= FLOOR:
                ball = ball + v
                array.append(round(ball,2))
                if v <= 0:
                    direction = 'DOWN'
            else:
                ball = FLOOR
                array.append(ball)
                direction = 'UP'
                v *= COEFFICIENT

class textBouncy:
    array = bounce()

    def __init__(self, font, message, fontcolor, amount=10):
        # Render the font message
        self.base = font.render(message, 0, fontcolor)
        # bounce amount (height)
        self.amount = amount
        #size = rect of maximum height/width of text
        self.size = self.base.get_rect().inflate(0, amount).size
        #normalise array to meet height restriction
        self.array = [round(-x/(500/amount),2) for x in array]

    def animate(self): 
        # create window surface s
        s = pygame.Surface(self.size)
        # height = max inflated height
        height = self.size[1]
        # define a step-sized rectangle in the location of the step
        src = Rect(0, 0, self.base.get_width(), height)
        # moves the message according to the array list. 
        dst = src.move(0, self.array[i])
        if (i + 1) == len(self.array):
            global i
            i = 0
        # blits the information onto the screen
        s.blit(self.base, dst, src)
        return s

entry_info = 'Bouncing ball text'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()

    #create text renderer
    i = 0
    array = bounce()
    bigfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 60)
    white = 255, 255, 255
    renderer = textBouncy(bigfont, entry_info, white, 16) 
    text = renderer.animate()

    #create a window the correct size
    win = pygame.display.set_mode(text.get_size())
    win.blit(text, (0, 10))
    pygame.display.flip()

    #run animation loop
    finished = 0
    while True:
        pygame.time.delay(10)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        text = renderer.animate()
        i += 1
        win.blit(text, (0, 10)) # blits the finished product from animate
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

(Quote) "it all comes down to math really" Kay so you need to - the y axis when you want to make it go up and + the x axis to make it go side ways you could make it go up and down will moveing it horizontally and then when it reaches a point it will stop moving horizontally and just bonce up and down +ing it more every time

That was my 100$ which took me 5 mins to write

Comment: thanks but I'm happy with the 'bounce' - I don't want the text to move along the x-axis, just move on the y-axis (I should have been more clear about this).  It's just getting the text animation to blit correctly to the screen that I'm having trouble with - would have put up pics to illustrate this but my rep's not high enough :(

Answer (score 0):

After revisiting this I managed to work this out - I needed to add everything I blitted down to compensate for the bounce up. So in the __init__function:

```
self.array = [round(-x/(500/amount),2)**+self.amount** for x in array]
```

Works perfectly now :)